# Typescript JSDoc comments not showing up in intellisense in vscode

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a javascript codebase, where i am adding type definitions so that VSCode intellisense can help with the types and descriptions, even in js files. I have not been able to get my JSDoc comments to show up in the js file though, even though the types show up correctly.

TRY 1

```
interface RunFunction {
  /**
   * @param argv arguments passed from command line
   * @param config global config
   * @returns void
   */
  (
    argv: typeof import('./index.js').argv,
    config: typeof import('./index.js').config,
  ): void;
}
```

TRY 2

```
/**
 * @param argv arguments passed from command line
 * @param config global config
 * @returns void
*/
interface RunFunction {
  (
    argv: typeof import('./index.js').argv,
    config: typeof import('./index.js').config,
  ): void;
}
```

TRY 3

```
interface RunFunction {
  (
    /** arguments passed from command line */
    argv: typeof import('./index.js').argv,
    /** global config */
    config: typeof import('./index.js').config,
  ): void;
}
```

I have also tried different combinations of the above. But when i try to use it in a js file, although I do see the types being correctly suggested, i don't see the comments / description at all.

This does not seem to work in [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhFgCgAIWgBADgQwE7ILbTQcwG7ao4CuGApgHYAuAztCjTWQCbQBmqA9lgMbcbIKrADYBLCmSiwEKdL04U2onNBzDOAI2TDofRcqlx4qMlWKoKdPJ1HNDwKOKplUbZDzLQASsQoAxXx4ARmgAbyloAAoI6EJ8AC4w6GZkZ0SAEVSyABpoCkwyRJoqVHEVAF9smN0FJRxE0N0gxIpSDRdcngAmIpKy6EqIgEpE61sAbihyqCg9YuhUX2bvXwCKbugAXnZAqlEFKNw8TtrlIbCIkzMLPOJhYUnIacgoYGAAWk%20v75-fv-%20AYCgb8ZpAnC43B4Vv5Al0LjBoKAIDAjLJMHECLhSJRaPRkIwWOwuPIMAIhNAxBJDDI0Oi9HVVOotDp6QYUQgruZLNAxnYUQ4EdEEbEjg1klkMllcvlyL1ShQKlVhTV9PUksEWm0OroetBivLFcNRjZmI9nrMFPNFhRdT4Yes4ds2Lt9hRDkRjiq6udwgjOTdWvczaC3sCw%20GI5HPqDwa53J47WseABmeGxIWxWJIuLY6h0BhMVgcbg1UmCETiTwgAWZjFilJpaCZZzSgpy-qDZXZtSabRe5SwGuZ1lqxoa24YdqoTq6-UdpWxEY8k3Bl6QOZUBa%20ZOJROwrY7dZ7A6RI4nVU%20y6mLm3INTIA) as well, so it might very well be a limitation of JSDoc implementation in TS and not a limitation of VScode or the project configuration.

Is there another way to define these types so that the comments / description show up properly in intellisense?

Answer (score 1):

Both try 2 and try 3 are correct and you should get JSDoc descriptions when you use the typed objects (see images below)

---

One thing you need to keep ind mind is that when you write:

```
const run2: RunFunc2 = function (argv, config) {
  return null;
}
```

The typing (and associated JSDoc) gets applied after the definition. In other words, the compiler (TS language server) will first read the function definition, and then apply the typing to `run2` similar to a a cast operation.

The compiler will apply typings to the function definition as a from of type inference because the function needs to be a valid subtype of the defined interface, but will not propagate the documentation. I don't know why this is the case, but my guesses are that it may be because the the documentation may not fully apply to the subtype itself, or (more probably) because JSDoc is a separate thing from TypeScript types so it does not get the same treatment.

If you want the documentation inside the definition you will need to document the function itself:

```
const run2: RunFunc2 = /**
 * @param argv arguments passed from command line
 * @param config global config
 * @returns void
*/function (argv, config) {
  return null;
};
```

**Note that this is not necessarily how the compiler (language server) works, just how I found the behaviour to match in practice**

---

Images taken from the TS playground you've linked:

[image: try 2 usage]
[image: try 3 usage]

Comment: so, there is no easy way to get the comments while inside the function definition, (which is where it makes the most sense, because i want other devs to follow this contract and understand what each parameter means when they write the function logic)

Comment: As far as I know, no. The closest thing I can think up is making a class interface with a function property called `run` with the docs. In which case when implementing the interface via a class you will have docs when you hover over the `run` method, but again not within the actual definition body. This may be because doc comments are generally (not just in JS/TS) aimed to be read when using a function so that you don't have to open the actual definition.